# How to get list of printers not printing direct?

Tags: vb.net, bitflags

I need a list of printers that DO NOT print direct. Getting a list that do print direct seems reasonably easy. But how to do the opposite?

```
    Dim PrintServer As New SysPrint.PrintServer
    Dim arrFlags(0) As SysPrint.EnumeratedPrintQueueTypes
    arrFlags(0) = System.Printing.EnumeratedPrintQueueTypes.DirectPrinting
    Dim QColl As SysPrint.PrintQueueCollection = PrintServer.GetPrintQueues(arrFlags)
```

[PrintServer.GetPrintQueues Method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms552938(v=vs.110).aspx)

[EnumeratedPrintQueueTypes Enumeration](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.printing.enumeratedprintqueuetypes(v=vs.100).aspx)

MSDN says that the EnumeratedPrintQueueTypes has a FlagsAttribute attribute that allows a bitwise combination of its member values. So I should be able to specify NOT direct somehow. How do I do it?

I tried to do this `arrFlags(0) = Not System.Printing.EnumeratedPrintQueueTypes.DirectPrinting` but that returned no results. Clearly incorrect.

So how do I manipulate the flags attribute to eliminate all printers printing direct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is one way to do it but it seems very inelegant:

```
    'get full list
    Dim PrintServer As New SysPrint.PrintServer
    Dim QColl As SysPrint.PrintQueueCollection = PrintServer.GetPrintQueues()

    'get those not printing direct 
    Dim Qcoll2 As List(Of SysPrint.PrintQueue) = QColl.Where(Function(x) Not (x.IsDirect)).ToList

    'select name only
    Dim strList As List(Of String) = Qcoll2.Select(Function(x) x.Name).ToList
```